# How to remove decimal separator if the decimal part is zero?

Tags: c#, excel, formatting, closedxml

I'm using [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) to create a excel spreadsheet. The issue takes place while formatting cells, containg percentages.

The format I came up to is `0.##%`.

It works well when the decimal part is not zero, it shows: `1,15%`; but when it's integral-valued, it leaves the decimal separator visible, while hiding zeroes, for example: `5,%`.

How can I make it hide the decimal separator as well?

Here is a small program, demonstrating the issue:

```
XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();
var ws = wb.AddWorksheet("test");

string format = "0.##%";

var cell = ws.Cell(1, 1);
cell.SetValue(5.2M / 100);
cell.Style.NumberFormat.Format = format;

cell = ws.Cell(1, 2);
cell.SetValue(5M / 100);
cell.Style.NumberFormat.Format = format;

wb.SaveAs("test.xlsx");
```

and the output is

[image]

Comment: What does the format string "#.##%" produce?

Comment: @Jason I use `0.##%`, not `#.##%` as your variant would not print zero at all; compare `0,5%` and `,5%`. And the prolblem remains, as it also prints the decimal separator

Comment: Then I would suggest using conditional formatting. The format string doesn't seem to support what you want to achieve. Not that I can see. http://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Conditional%20Formatting&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: Best source I can locate on this is http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/CustomFormats.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to Jason for the link to [CLOSED XML: Conditional Formatting](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Conditional%20Formatting&referringTitle=Documentation)!

Thanks to this I managed to find the way to apply conditional formatting I needed:

```
cell.AddConditionalFormat()
    .WhenEquals(
        string.Format(
            "=TRUNC(${0}${1})", 
            cell.WorksheetColumn().ColumnLetter(),
            cell.WorksheetRow().RowNumber()))
    .NumberFormat
    .Format = "general\"%\"";
```

I gave up using percent format specifier, as it makes me divide by 100. 
From [Excel Custom Number Formats](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/CustomFormats.htm):

> %     Percentage. Microsoft Excel multiplies by 100 and adds the %
>   character.

Now I simply add `%` as a string, not as a format specifier.

So the main number format is `0.##\"%\"`, but when the value's decimal part is zero, I substitute the number format to the general one with `%` in the end using conditional formatting.